# ggplot2: Show difference in values over time with an arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set with scores to questions asked over two years.  Each question has a 2015 value and a 2016 value.  I would like to plot each and then show the different between the 2015 value and the 2016 value.  Did the score go up or down or stay the same?  I was thinking it might be useful to connect pairs of points with a line (or an arrow) to show the direction of change, but I'm having a hard time getting ggplot to do this.  Here is my code example:

```
df <- read.table(text = "question y2015 y2016
q1 90 50
q2 80 60
q3 70 90
q4 90 60
q5 30 20", header = TRUE)

g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=question))
g1 <- g1 + geom_point(aes(y=y2015, color="y2015"), size=4)
g1 <- g1 + geom_point(aes(y=y2016, color="y2016"), size=4)
g1
```

Different approaches to visualizing this are welcome.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer right now, but if you have a fair number of questions (you mention ~100 in a comment below) I would do a scatterplot of 2015 scores (x) vs 2016 scores (y). Add in a 45-degree line and dots above the line are improvements, and the correlation between the two years is clearly visible (and outliers should stand out as well).

Comment: @onself; Could be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109623/remove-legend-elements-of-one-specific-geom-show-legend-false-does-not-do-t/38110017#38110017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still a bit ugly and needs fine tuning but it got arrows ;)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot2df <- read.table(text = "question y2015 y2016
q1 90 50
                 q2 80 60
                 q3 70 90
                 q4 90 60
                 q5 30 20", header = TRUE)


df <- ggplot2df %>% 
  mutate(direction = ifelse(y2016 - y2015 > 0, "Up", "Down"))%>%
  melt(id = c("question", "direction"))


g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=question, y = value, color = variable, group = question )) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = direction), arrow=arrow())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think a "dumbbell" chart would work, too. Here I've reshaped your data to long.

```
df <- read.table(text = "question y2015 y2016
q1 90 50
q2 80 60
q3 70 90
q4 90 60
q5 30 20", header = TRUE)

df.long <- 
  reshape(df, varying = names(df)[2:3],
        direction = 'long',
        #ids = 'question',
        times = 2015:2016,
        v.names = 'perc',
        timevar = 'year'
        )

ggplot(df.long, aes(x = perc, y = question))+
  geom_line(aes(group = question))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(year)), size = 2)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1', name = 'Year')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you facet by question and put year on the x-axis, you can highlight the trend direction with color and use the x-axis to show the passage of time.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(df %>% melt(id.var="question") %>% 
         group_by(question) %>% 
         mutate(Direction=ifelse(diff(value)>0,"Up","Down")), 
       aes(x=gsub("y","",variable), y=value, color=Direction, group=question)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  geom_path(arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.1,"in")), show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(. ~ question) +
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=15)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) +
  labs(x="Year", y="Value")
```

With this encoding of aesthetics, you probably don't need the legend, and adding arrows to the line segments may be superfluous as well, but I've left them in for illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?
Some reshaping of the data is needed and taken care of with the function `gather` from the very useful library `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- df %>% gather(year, value, y2015:y2016) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color= question)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(group=interaction(question)))
g1
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice viz. It's easy to identify the one question which had an increase.

Comment: This is nice.  However, in the real data, I have many more questions (~100) and they text for each is longer than "q1".  So, I think that visualizing it this way will be too cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

This website seems to have the solution you're looking for (it's a handy site):

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/connected_scatterplot_ggplot2.html

Excerpt:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(babynames)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)

# data
data <- babynames %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Ashley", "Amanda")) %>%
  filter(sex=="F") %>%
  filter(year>1970) %>%
  select(year, name, n) %>%
  spread(key = name, value=n, -1)

# Select a few date to label the chart
tmp_date <- data %>% sample_frac(0.3)

# plot 
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Amanda, y=Ashley, label=year)) +
     geom_point(color="#69b3a2") +
     geom_text_repel(data=tmp_date) +
     geom_segment(color="#69b3a2", 
                  aes(
                    xend=c(tail(Amanda, n=-1), NA), 
                    yend=c(tail(Ashley, n=-1), NA)
                  ),
                  arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))
      ) +
      theme_ipsum()
```

[image: chart]